# Can I queue up multiple spells or abilities?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

It's rather annoying to have to watch each of my casters to make sure that their various skills go off; it'd be nice if I could queue up 2 or 3 spells in a row to make sure that a nice combination goes through while I focus on microing my front line. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

**There sure is!**

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting actions to queue them in order. This also works with movement, and even works in exploration mode to set waypoints, or to disarm multiple traps in a set order! No more fighting with bad pathfinding! (Maybe. If you remember to set movement this way every time.)

Comment: Is that really all there is to it? I am having difficulty getting this to work in paused mode

Comment: @GodEmperorDune Works for me, yeah. You need to hold down shift through the entire process of selecting and targeting each spell in the queue.